# Problems with FastICA, modifying an independent source changes all outputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running into a problem when using sklearn FastICA. I'm trying to predict what the 'measured' variables (X in the code) would be if one of the predicted 'sources' was changing in a given way. I'm modifying this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-ica-blind-source-separation-py).

I think the problem is that FastICA approximates the 'mixing' matrix but ica.mixing_ is very different from what I used to generate the data. I understand that the mixing matrix is undefined since the product np.dot(S, A.T) is what is relevant and changing S to S*a and A to A/a will yield the same result for all a != 0.

Any ideas? Thanks for reading and helping

Here is my code.

```
    # this is exactly how the example start
    np.random.seed(0)
    n_samples = 200
    time = np.linspace(0, 8, n_samples)

    s1 = np.sin(2 * time)  # Signal 1 : sinusoidal signal
    s2 = np.sign(np.sin(3 * time))  # Signal 2 : square signal
    s3 = signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * time)  # Signal 3: saw tooth signal

    S = np.c_[s1, s2, s3]
    S += 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=S.shape)  # Add noise

    S /= S.std(axis=0)  # Standardize data
    # Here I'm changing the example. I'm modifying the 'mixing' array 
    # such that s1 is not mixed with neither s2 nor s3
    A = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 1.0], [0, 1.0, 2.0]])  # Mixing matrix
    # Mix data, 
    X = np.dot(S, A.T)  # Generate observations

    # Compute ICA
    ica = FastICA()
    S_ = ica.fit_transform(X)  # Reconstruct signals
    A_ = ica.mixing_  # Get estimated mixing matrix

    # We can `prove` that the ICA model applies by reverting the unmixing.
    assert np.allclose(X, np.dot(S_, A_.T) + ica.mean_)

    # Here is where my real code starts,
    # Now modify source s1
    s1 *= 1.1
    S = np.c_[s1, s2, s3]
    S /= S.std(axis=0)  # Standardize data

    # regenerate observations. 
    # Note that original code in the example uses np.dot(S, A.T) 
    # (that doesn't work either). I'm using ica.inverse_transform 
    # because it is what is documented but also because there is an
    # FastICA.mean_ that is not documented and I'm hoping 
    # inverse_transform uses it in the right way.
    # modified_X =  np.dot(S, A.T)   # does not work either
    modified_X = ica.inverse_transform(S)

    # check that last 2 observations are not changed
    # The original 'mixing' array was defined to mix s2 and s3 but not s1
    # Next tests fail
    np_testing.assert_array_almost_equal(X[:, 1], modified_X[:, 1])
    np_testing.assert_array_almost_equal(X[:, 2], modified_X[:, 2])
```

Comment: The coefficients of the mixing matrix will give you the transformation that makes s1, s2 and s3 maximally independent. If you change s1, then you may as well expect ALL entries of the mixing matrix to change, not only one of them.

Comment: "The coefficients of the mixing matrix will give you the transformation that makes s1, s2 and s3 maximally independent" I agree with this statement but not with the 2nd one. Lets stay that I recorded 3 instruments. Instrument 1 (room 1) is completely isolated from instruments 2 and 3 (room 2). I record and do ica on this data. If I asked musicians to play again why can't I use the already predicted 'mixing' to predict what the microphones in each room will record? Why would microphones in room 2 now predict anything from instrument 1?
Thanks again

Comment: Another way to look at it is that I'm not changing the mixing matrix because I'm not re-fitting the model. The matrix is fixed and I'm just changing the sources

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my findings in case it helps anyone.
I think there are 2 problems with the code I posted

1. When fitting the ICA, the exact 'mixing' matrix is not found and the solution will be leaking source 1 into all measured outputs. The result should be small with lots of data but it should still be there. However, I don't see a change in behavior when increasing the amount of faked data nor when changing FastICA's max_iter or tol parameters.
2. Order of sources is unpredictable, in the code I was assuming that found S_ was in the same order as S (which is wrong). Looping over all sources (after fit_transform), changing one at a time I see results that are close to what I expect. Two of the sources (1 and 2 for me) have impacts mostly on measured variables 2 and 3 and the 3rd source has most impact on measured variable 1 with some minor impact on variables 2 and 3.